# How to count the number of votes for each star in fivestar?

Tags: 7, rating

I'm using Drupal 7, [Voting API](https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi) and [Fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar).

I try to count the number of votes for each star, and display the percentage, like :

[image]

It is at present possible to have only the number of total vote.

How can I achieve this?
With Voting API (`hook_votingapi_results_alter`) or Views ?

For information, [i'm using comments for rating nodes](https://www.drupal.org/node/1308114).

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module? You could write an SQL, equivalent to the existing answer, and then use it's charting facilities to create a chart (report) from it that looks similar to what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Once i tried to find some function that could do it. But i found just
 fivestar_get_votes($entity_type, $id, $tag = 'vote', $uid = NULL). It returns full voting score.

You can get some info [here](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!fivestar!fivestar.module/function/fivestar_get_votes/7) or on other sites.

I think it is possible with some sql queries EG:

```
   $query = db_select('votingapi_vote', 'vote');
   $query->condition('vote.entity_type', 'node');
   $query->condition('vote.entity_id', $nid);
   $query->condition('vote.tag', 'vote');
   $query->condition('vote.value', '60');
   $query->addField('vote', 'uid');
   $three_stars = $query->countQuery()->execute()->fetchField();
```

Here $nid is your your node's nid and 60 means three stars (20 - 1 star, 40 - 2 stars etc), vote.tag is tag that you assigned for your votes.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. It's strange that there is not a "simpler" solution. I am going to try but it seems to me heavy for the need...

Comment: Yes, i had the same issue and just these count queries could help me. It seems any statistics functions are not previewed for the Fivestar module.